# Understanding built-in Labels

Tags: kubernetes

I'm new to kubernetes and I'm trying to understand how labels work on a node. We have eks server version 1.14 running in our organization. I'm trying to change built-in deprecated labels.

In aws-node daemonset, I want to replace beta.kubernetes.io/os to kubernetes.io/os and beta.kubernetes.io/arch to kubernetes.io/arch.

Since it both beta.kubernetes.io/arch and kubernetes.io/arch labels when i describe a node.

- Is it safe to go ahead remove the beta.kubernetes.io/arch and
  beta.kubernetes.io/os labels?
- I want to understand if I change the label, what are its effects?
- Does Pods running on that node are affected?
- Can apiVersion: apps/v1 change built-in labels?
- Can I just run `kubectl label node "node-name" beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64 -` to remove the labels?
- Is there a need to apply the daemonset ?

  ```
  kind: DaemonSet
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  metadata:
    name: aws-node
    namespace: kube-system
    labels:
      k8s-app: aws-node
  spec:
    updateStrategy:
      type: RollingUpdate
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        k8s-app: aws-node
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          k8s-app: aws-node
      spec:
        priorityClassName: system-node-critical
        affinity:
          nodeAffinity:
            requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
              nodeSelectorTerms:
                - matchExpressions:
                    - key: "beta.kubernetes.io/os"
                      operator: In
                      values:
                        - linux
                    - key: "beta.kubernetes.io/arch"
                      operator: In
                      values:
                        - amd64
  ```

  kubectl describe node/ip-10-xx-xx-xx.ec2.internal -n kube-system

```
    Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                        beta.kubernetes.io/instance-type=c4.xlarge
                        beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
                        failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=us-east-1
                        failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=us-east-1a
                        group=nodes
                        kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
                        kubernetes.io/hostname=ip-10-182-32-156.ec2.internal
                        kubernetes.io/os=linux
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/labels-annotations-taints/#kubernetesioarch) we can read that `beta.kubernetes.io/arch` and `beta.kubernetes.io/os` are deprecated since version 1.14 ([removed on version 1.18](https://v1-16.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/#deprecations-and-removals)) and `kubernetes.io` should be used instead.

You are using version 1.14 and there is no reason for you to change/remove these labels. Changing them would add one more layer of complication to your cluster when you want to add a node for example (you have to always keep in mind that you have non-stock labels in your nodes).

> - Is it safe to go ahead remove the beta.kubernetes.io/arch and beta.kubernetes.io/os labels?

It's safe but unnecessary unless you have applications running on mixed clusters and you are using these labels.

> - I want to understand if I change the label, what are its effects?

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubernetes-api/labels-annotations-taints/#betakubernetesioarch-deprecated) we can read:

kubernetes.io/arch: This can be handy if you are mixing arm and x86 nodes.

kubernetes.io/os: This can be handy if you are mixing operating systems in your cluster (for example: mixing Linux and Windows nodes).

So these labels are there for your convenience, you can use them to keep track of things.

> - Does Pods running on that node are affected?

No, pods are still going to be normally scheduled .

> - Can I just run  `kubectl label node "node-name" beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64 -`  to remove the labels?

To remove the label you can run:

```
kubectl label node "node-name" beta.kubernetes.io/arch-
```

To remove from all nodes:

```
kubectl label nodes --all beta.kubernetes.io/arch-
```

> - Is there a need to apply the daemonset ?

I particularly don't see a need for that.